# Retaining order of moving elements in a list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've created a section of spans that when clicked on move into another html element and when clicked on while within the target element returns back to the section of spans.

My question is, how can I return the clicked span back to it's ORIGINAL position in the list of spans?

I can think of one way that might work and would involve using CSS child selectors, but that can become very complicated and I'm looking for a more intuitive way.

As it happens now, the span in question returns to the end of the list.

```
<div id="genres">
   <?php
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM genres ORDER BY genre DESC';
    $genres = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($genres)){
        echo "<span class='genre'>";
        echo ucfirst($row['genre']);
        echo "</span>";
```

The above simply outputs the data into seperate spans styled to be clickable elements that look similar to buttons.

When a span is clicked on it is moved into an empty div.

My Jquery:

```
$("span.genre").click(function(){
    // remove the span and move it to the empty div
    $(this).remove().appendTo('div#genres_select');

    // remove span from the empty div and puts it back in the list
    $('div#genres_select span.genre').click(function(){
        $(this).remove().appendTo('div#genres');
});
```

What is interesting and that I like is that when a clicked span is moved out of the list, all the other elements conform to fill it's space.

Ideally, I'm looking for the exact reverse action of clicking on a span, as if you pushed the rewind button.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How about just hiding the original spans and creating copies of them (with no ID or a different ID) to the target location? Then "rewinding" would just involve removing the new one and re-showing the original.

Comment: Thought precisely of this :-)

Comment: Those `span`s won't be keyboard accessible. You're better off replacing them with real `button` elements. http://www.w3.org/TR/UNDERSTANDING-WCAG20/keyboard-operation.html

Answer (score 0):

Add the position to the dom.

```
  $pos = 0
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($genres)){
    echo "<span orgPos='".$pos."' class='genre'>";
    echo ucfirst($row['genre']);
    echo "</span>";
    $pos++
  }
```

The javascript looks for the lower neighbor

```
   $('div#genres_select span.genre').click(function(){
    var pos = $(this).attr("orgPos");
    var neighbor = false;
    $('#genres span.genre').each(function(){
            if (!neighbor && ($( this ).attr("orgPos") < pos ))
                  neighbor = $( this );   
           })
    $(this).remove();
    sibling.after(this)
   }
```

You will need to figure out what to do if it is the first element or only one element in the list.

Comment: I can see your logic here - assign each span a position and use that to return a span back to a logical order in the sequence but I feel there's got to be a smoother way that doesn't require work-arounds for specific elements (first or only one item).

Comment: Adding attribute is not a workaround it is standard web development. You will be hard pressed to find any site that does not do this. Hiding an element and creating a copy is a work around.  If you want keep with best practice you could use attribute data-*  like data-pos.  `$( this ).data("pos")`